# Structure of phosphates in nucleotides

Tags: dna, nucleic-acids, phosphate

Nucleotides are made up of a heterocyclic nitrogenous base, a sugar (only ribose or deoxyribose), and a phosphate. In nucleotides, obviously the nitrogenous base matters as its variations dictate the production of certain amino acids, and the sugar can only be ribose (in RNA) or deoxyribose (in DNA), but does the type of phosphate matter? I've seen that a nucleoside describes the nitrogenous base and the sugar alone, and there are nucleoside monophosphates, nucleoside diphosphates and nucleoside triphosphates.

Do these three variations differentiate; when it dictating the production of amino acids; when looking at any sort physical variation; in any sort of way; or are all three just the same as each other??
Also, do all of the phosphates have to look like this?
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Phosphate-group.png). Or can they look like this (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Phosphodiester-group.png). If they can look like the second image, then similarly to the question above, does it make any difference?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the Biology Stack Exchange! Interesting question, do you think you could try and distill it down to one question? I'm not sure if you're trying to ask about phosphate (of which there is only one: PO4) or asking about nucleotides.

Comment: I have cleaned up your title and removed irrelevant tags. You are asking a very basic chemical question about chemical structures, the only complication of which is the ionization of the phosphate at physiological pH.  Read and understand the WIkipedia or Berg et al (NCBI Bookshelf) pages about the structure of  nuceotides, phosphate, and nucleic acids and you will be able to answer your own question, which will no doubt be put on hold shortly.

Comment: 1. Do the differentiations of possible phosphates (e.g. mono-,di-,tri-, isomers) as components of a nucleotide affect the function of that nucleotide?

Comment: 2. Is it often that nucleotides are found with more than one regular phosphate group (first link in question) as a component?

Comment: @LucasDyson-Diaz please do not ping *everyone* every time you respond. This is exactly why you can only ping one person per comment. You now have two very basic chemistry questions, which (again) can be answered by reading the relevant Wikipedia pages. The answer to both of your questions is yes.

Comment: @MattDMo (to the first question) How so? How does the phosphate group(s) it affect the nucleotide?

Comment: @LucasDyson-Diaz you'll have to read the resources we've all suggested to learn more about nucleotide mono-, di-, and tri-phosphates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well it turns out that when nucleotides are bonded together in a strand of DNA/RNA (nucleic acid) they **ALWAYS HAVE only one phosphate group** attached to their nucleoside (nucleoside = sugar + nitrogenous base (without phosphate)).

However, **when they are by themselves, they are more often found with two or three phosphate groups** as oppose to just the one. For this reason, the definition of a nucleotide is *often misunderstood* as it refers to containing one OR MORE phosphates, in reality, **the official definition of a nucleotide states that only one phosphate group is present**...

**An example** of a (*so-called*) "nucleotide" is ATP (adenosine triphosphate); it follows all of the rules that the *misunderstood definition of a nucleotide* states (these are; a nitrogenous base (adenine); a pentose sugar (ribose); and one "OR MORE" phosphate groups (triphosphate)). **However, according to the official definition of a nucleotide, it is not, in fact, a nucleotide**! It is instead considered a '**nucleoside triphosphate**', since it is a nucleoside. with three phosphate groups (it is also a nucleotide with two additional phosphate groups, but I guess 'nucleotide-with-a-diphosphate' attachment doesn't roll off the tongue so well as nucleoside triphosphate).

Finally, as in nucleic acids and indeed anywhere else (according to the official definition of the nucleotide), there is only one phosphate group allowed to attached to each nucleoside (regular phosphate group) to form a nucleotide (officially). **Therefore there is no variation allowed in the phosphate groups** (since there's only one and they bond to other nucleotides, in the same way, every time (in nucleic acids)), furthermore in the pentose sugar the only variation allowed is whether it is a ribose (in RNA) or a deoxyribose (in DNA). **So the phosphate-sugar backbone of the DNA strands and the RNA strands** (nucleic acids) **are consistent throughout the entire strand** (and each strand of its type; differentiating only in the type of pentose sugar it consists of (ribose/deoxyribose)). Consequently, **there is no phosphate-sugar backbone variation within DNA strands or RNA strands**, for the phosphate or the pentose sugar to make any genetic difference to genetic material (those strands); **only the nitrogenous bases and their sequences can make a difference to the genetic material**...